# How do USB ASIC Miners Work?

Tags: asic, mining-setup

How do the USB ASIC miners work?  Do you just plug them into a power source and they start mining?  Do you have to set them up for a first time?  Do you need to use a mining program still?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USB ASIC miners require some sort of control program that sends work to the miners and collects the results. You set them up in that control program. [BFGMiner](http://bfgminer.org/) is one such program.